# Certificate and correct answer for the question

Tags: wpf

I am preparing for an exam and studying questions. However I have one question which in my opinion the answer is wrong. Here's the question where the correct answer is D:

> You use Microsoft .NET Framework 4 to
>   create a Windows Presentation
>   Foundation (WPF) application. The
>   application has a window named
>   MainWindow that has a StackPanel
>   control named sp as the root element.
>   You want to create a Button control
>   that contains a TextBlock control with
>   the "Save" Text property. You need to
>   create the control dynamically and add
>   the control to sp. Which code segment
>   should you write in the constructor of
>   the MainWindow class

A:

```
Button btn = new Button();
TextBlock text = new TextBlock();
text.Text = "Save";
btn.Content = text;
sp.DataContext = btn;
```

B:

```
Button btn = new Button();
TextBlock text = new TextBlock();
text.Text = "Save";
btn.Content = text;
sp.Children.Add(btn);
```

C:

```
Button btn = new Button();
TextBlock text = new TextBlock();
text.Text = "Save";
sp.Children.Add(btn);
sp.Children.Add(text);
```

D:

```
Button btn = new Button();
TextBlock text = new TextBlock();
text.Text = "Save";
btn.ContentTemplateSelector.SelectTemplate(text, null);
sp.Children.Add(btn);
```

In my opinion the correct answer is B? Do you have any sugesstions?

Comment: i think you are right and B is correct answer. Other answers does't work correct.

Comment: Never coded .NET or WPF, but I'd also choose B. It seems to assign the properties of the two objects correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're right. Answer D makes no sense at all, because:

1. you don't need the `ContentTemplateSelector`, since you're defining the content explicitly
2. `ContentTemplateSelector` shouldn't be used explicitly, it's used by ContentControl when it needs to render non-visual content
3. `ContentTemplateSelector` is null by default, so the code in answer D would crash with a `NullReferenceException`

Answer (score 3):

I passed the same exam last week. And I agree that the correct answer should be B.
You can try both in a sample application and you will see that D does not work.

Comment: hi Jogy. Can you please tell me how was the exam? Was the questions similar to what practice tests contains? I've already checked that D is not working

Comment: I had exactly this question and others too. I passed with 982 points.